# How to enumerate the users chosen professional designation from relational database using linq lambda C# MVC razor in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

Good Day, Fellow coders!

i'm a bit of a novice when it comes to MVC C#, but here is my problem. i have three relational MySQL tables; Users, titles, and usertitles.

Users looks like this:

```
+---------------+----------+
| currentUserId | UserName |
+---------------+----------+
|             1 | Dave     |
+---------------+----------+
```

Titles look like this:

```
+---------+-------+
| TitleId | Title |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | BS    |
|       2 | MD    |
|       3 | PHD   |
|       4 | BA    |
+---------+-------+
```

...and UserTitles looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+
| UserId | TitleId |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       1 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
+--------+---------+
```

Now in my view i want to display "Dave, BS,MD,PHD,BA" based of of the professional designation assigned to Dave in the db.

now i can easily do this in a MySQL query, and it'll work:

```
select Title from titles
INNER JOIN UserTitles on UserTitles.TitleId = titles.TitleId
where UserTitles.UserId = currentUserId;
```

Now i have to turn this into Linq.Lambda. This is what i made, and it shows no errors.

In Controller:

```
ViewData.Add("FirstName", Users.Name);

var thisresult =
_contentService.Titles.Join(_contentService.UserTitles,
x => x.Id, y => y.TitleId, (x, y) => new {x, y})
.Where(@t => @t.y.UserId == currentUserId)
.Select(@t => new SelectListItem {Value = @t.x.TitleString}).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
(thanks for all the support)

```
IEnumerable<String> thisresult = _contentService.Titles
.Join(_contentService.UserTitles.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId),
t => t.Id,
ut => ut.TitleId,
(t, ut) => t.TitleString);

var model = new ManageUserViewModel()
{
 Titlelist = thisresult.ToList()
};

return View(model);
```

where _contentService calls my db.

In ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titlelist { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE**

```
public IEnumerable<String> Titlelist { get; set; }
```

In View:

```
 @ViewBag.FirstName,
 @foreach (var x in Model.Titlelist)
            {@x.Value}
```

**UPDATE**

```
@foreach (var title in Model.Titlelist)
            {
                @Html.Raw(title)
            }
```

The OutPut:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Specified method is not supported.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why are you using an anonymous type at all, when you've only got a single property to project to? And why are you calling `ToString()` on the result of a `Join` query?

Comment: im sure my novicity is much cringe, but that join query is what i  found on stack overflow in a similar situation to mine. There are parts of it that i dont understand, such as (x,y) => new {x,y}... im very new to lambda.

Comment: I would strongly suggest getting to know it in the safety of LINQ to Objects first, then move on to SQL via NHibernate or whatever when you understand more of what's going on.

Comment: FYI, you call ToList() twice, which is redundant, and in any case, your model property is IEnumerable, in which case, you don't have to call ToList at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thisresult =
_contentService.Titles.Join(_contentService.UserTitles, 
x => x.Id, y => y.TitleId, (x, y) => new {x, y})
.Where(@t => @t.y.UserId == currentUserId)
.Select(@t => new {Title = @t.x.TitleString}).ToList();
```

Changed ToString() to ToList();

**EDIT :**

```
var thisresult =
_contentService.Titles.Join(_contentService.UserTitles, 
x => x.Id, y => y.TitleId, (x, y) => new {x, y})
.Where(@t => @t.y.UserId == currentUserId)
.Select(@t => new SelectListItem{
  Selected = //write your stuff here ,
  Text = //write your stuff here //,
  Value = //write your stuff here  }).ToList();
```

**EDIT 2**

```
var thisresult =  _contentService.Titles.Join(_contentService.UserTitles, 
x => x.TitleId, y => y.TitleId, (x, y) => new {x, y})
.Where(@t => @t.y.UserId == currentUserId)
.Select(@t => new SelectListItem{
  Selected = //write your stuff here ,
  Text = //write your stuff here //,
  Value = //write your stuff here  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please read these to learn more about LINQ : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286255/Using-LINQ-Queries

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Download  : https://www.linqpad.net/ It will help you to learn linq

Comment: WOW! thank you! great resource! When i put ToList(); i got the error:
Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<{Title:String}>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectedListItem>'

Comment: Please look into this youtube channel : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsncc8dYIgY&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXCHPed2Q9oBkgvzw9Re8hC

Comment: its pretty much the same as stated above. I'm really good at MySQL querying and i can do simple lambda queries. but, man, doing joins are tough. So i like the challenge of staying 100% in lambda only.

i think from that error i might have to change the enumeration type. but im not sure. I appreciate you help, Vishal!

Comment: Books : http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Framework-Developer-Reference/dp/0735640572
http://www.amazon.com/Depth-3rd-Edition-Jon-Skeet/dp/161729134X
these are my fav books.

Comment: @NeoSketo : Sorry I did not get you.

Comment: the edit clears with no errors yet has no results. i did this quick query: var userSelectedTItlesId =
                _contentService.UserTitles.Where(q => q.UserId == currentUserId).Select(q => q.TitleId).ToList();

and got count=4. And a list of all the TitleIds. hmm.... I'm getting closer.

Comment: @NeoSketo : Check my edit, maybe join condition was not correct.

Comment: check out without errors but still yields no results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ alternative:

```
var thisresult = from t in _contentService.Titles
                join ut in _contentService.UserTitles on t.titleid equals ut.titleid
                where ut.userid == currentUserId
                select new SelectListItem
                {  Display = t.title, Value = t.titleId };
```

However, as Jon pointed out, if you're only using one property (title), you don't need to create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, you can just have `IEnumerable<string>`, and instead of select new SelectListItem... you would have `Select t.title;`

Comment: i tried this, but im not sure why thisresult is "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: What happens when you remove the where?

Comment: commenting out the where line gives me the same ""Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Try on t.titleid equals ut.titleid

Comment: commenting out that line breaks the join

Comment: Sorry, I meant switch the join, have t.TitleId equals ut.TitleId

Comment: it breaks when i switch the order. i think it has to be ut.titleid equals t.titleid

Comment: i updated my code based on everyones help. i changed the linq to lambda and i get a new error but i think im getting closer. i really appreciate your help :)